# Control ipython history length

Tags: python, ipython, qtconsole

The title pretty much says what I want.

I want to have more than 1000 lines of input in my ipython-history; which means that pressing arrow-up commands older are showing up. Is this possible? (probably somewhere in ipython-config()?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In http://2sn.org/python/ipython_config.py there is a

```
# c.TerminalInteractiveShell.history_length = 10000
```

Does it work?

Comment: Kind of. The data is obviously stored in history.sqlite, and I can find the corresponding entries there, but pressing the up-arrow doesn't bring the command back