# Increase IPython history length

Tags: python, ipython, input-history

I have tried increasing IPython history length following this post :
[Control ipython history length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061049/control-ipython-history-length) by changing `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.history_length` in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`.

The config file seems to be executed at startup (if I put `print('test-startup')` in the file, it's printed when I start IPython)

But it does not seems to have any influence, is there anyway to check the history size from inside the ipython (kinda like how you can do `echo $HISTSIZE; echo $HISTFILESIZE` in bash ?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using

```
In[3]: %config TerminalInteractiveShell.history_length
Out[3]: 10000
```

Answer (score 19):

In attempting to answer the question myself, I stumbled upon this question [as well this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061049/control-ipython-history-length) and found snippets that really didn't provide the OP with the complete, TL;DR information.

So for my own records and to make the answers on SO here more complete, I provided a quick implementation and check to "Increase iPython History Length."

### Generate the `iPython` config file

```
$ ipython profile create <profile name>
```

I just wanted this for my default config, so I ran:

```
$ ipython profile create
```

### Modify the `ipython_config.py` File

Running the above command creates an `ipython_config.py` file, which (on `*.nix` is stored at `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

These are the two lines that I uncommented and changed the values for:

[image]

### Check to Ensure the Implementation Worked

Fire up iPython and run the commands found in the accepted answer above to ensure our new `history_length = 100,000`.

```
benjamingross (develop*)$ ipython
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:14:23)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.3.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: %config TerminalInteractiveShell.history_length
Out[1]: 100000
```

Comment: Thank you for very detailed answer! :)

Comment: It's in the screenshot but I don't see it in the text: **you also want to increase the history_load_length value to access the history in IPython**.